# ZIP archive with a directory with cyrillic characters displays bad encoding

Tags: linux, bash, zip, debian

I archive the directory recursively using this command
`zip -r /directory/*`

I open the archive using the archive manager and see that the name of the directory is like this
`logs_2023-09-05T13-07-15Z_\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043D\u0446\u0438\u044F \u0416\u0414`

Name of directory - `logs_2023-09-05T13-07-15Z_станция ЖД`

Comment: What zip? Info-ZIP's zip? Some other zip? What version? The "archive manager" on what? From where? What version? Do you have an unzip command? What does it say? Your "question" has almost zero information. What's more, there is no question in the question! (Hint: A question ends with a question mark.)

Answer (score 0):

You may seek some zip manager that supports switching between multiple encodings on the fly.

To name a random one:

[image]

As for the command line, `7z`would be your choice

```
-scc{UTF-8|WIN|DOS} : set charset for for console input/output
-scs{UTF-8|UTF-16LE|UTF-16BE|WIN|DOS|{id}} : set charset for list files
```